# How to set path to Latex distribution in a .tex file?

Tags: paths

I am writing my CV and and I am modifying the `moderncv` package. Since Texlive can update packages and potentially overwrite my changes, I have copied the `moderncv` package inside my working folder.

However, the `moderncv.cls` file refers to files that are in the latex distribution folder.

How do I tell the `moderncv.cls` to find those packages from the default distribution folder?

Environment: MacOS 10.7 + MacTex

Comment: Unless moderncv is doing something very curious it should work out of the box. But I would advise you to rename your copy. At least you should change the `\ProvidesClass` declaration so that you always see in the log-file that you are using a modified class.

Comment: Well, actually, I get the error: `"The included LaTeX file "size1\@ptsize.clo" was not found"` on the copied `moderncv`. A search from the Terminal points to `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/`. If I copy the base folder into my working folder, problem is solved. However, I want my copied `moderncv` to _link_ to my tex distribution.

Comment: `\@ptsize` is defined in processing the options `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt`. i would guess that your revised `moderncv.cls` doesn't have those options.  since i have no access to that file, this can be no more than a guess, i'm afraid.

Comment: Run a small document starting with `\documentclass{article}`. If it finds `article.cls` in `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/` then your search pathes are ok and your problem lies elsewhere. (Your error message looks very curious). Make an example that demonstrates your problem and put it together with your modified class and the log-file somewhere for download.